# custom query for taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am using this query to show certain posts.

```
query_posts( array(
                    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
                    ),                      
                ) );
```

Now instead of showing all posts from `APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug` I would like to exclude them. I tried all solutions found in this form, but nothing worked. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

```
query_posts( array(
  'post_type'      => APP_POST_TYPE,
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'tax_query'      => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => APP_TAX_STORE,
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => $term->slug,
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
  ),
) );
```

Comment: great thank you, only thing I need now is to only show one item (post) from each APP_TAX_STORE taxonomy.